# Wire bathroom fan with light and vanity light?

Tags: electrical, bathroom-fixtures

Can anyone guide me on how to wire a bathroom fan with light and vanity light with one hot wire ?
[image]
[image]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

[3]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZfuN.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZfuN.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sF827.jpg)[image]

Comment: How was it wired before?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what you are trying to connect, and how you want the switches to work?

Comment: Post the picture before you disconnected the wires. You did take one? Which wire goes to what?

Comment: Posted a pic of how it was wired but fan and light turn on at the same time ?

Comment: Am i wiring something wrong ?